# Have screen reader pronounce all texts in the div

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I have a `div` defined as below. I want the every text in the `div` is pronounsed as user tab into this `div`. In this case,
when user tabs into the outer `div`, screen reader reads *item.X* and *item.Y* (item is a variable).

```
<div tabindex="0">
    <div>{{item.X}}</div>
    <div>{{item.Y}}</div>
 </div>
```

I tried to give this `div` a `role="link"`, and it reads everything, but this `div` is not a link so I don't think it is the right approach.

```
<div tabindex="0" role="link">
    <div>{{item.X}}</div>
    <div>{{item.Y}}</div>
 </div>
```

I also attempted to do the below, but it seems `aria-label` does not work with Angular Interpolation.

```
<div tabindex="0" role="link" aria-label="{{item.X}}">
    <div>{{item.X}}</div>
    <div>{{item.Y}}</div>
 </div>
```

What is the right way to achive my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tough to give a complete answer without seeing your real code in context.  I assume the sample code is just a simplification but I'll point out the issues in the sample.

Firstly, you have a `<div tabindex="0">`, which allows the keyboard focus to move to that element but that element doesn't appear to do anything.  It's not an interactive element.  There's a warning in the [html spec for `tabindex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/editing.html#the-tabindex-attribute).

> authors should only make elements focusable if they act as interactive controls or widgets

If your <div> **does** do something (perhaps you have a click handler in javascript), then you'd still have a problem because your <div> does not have any semantic meaning.  A screen reader will not know the purpose of the <div>.  That's when `role` comes into play.  If you designed your own link instead of using an <a> element, and your custom link was composed of <div> elements, that's when you'd have `role="link"` on your <div>.  The purpose of the role isn't to force all the text to be read.  The purpose is to convey to assistive technology (such as a screen reader) what the **purpose** of that object is.

As far as using `aria-label`, again, it depends on the semantic meaning of your element.  The `aria-label` is typically ignored on non-semantic elements, such as <div> or <span>.  See the W3 spec for "[Practical Support: aria-label, aria-labelledby and aria-describedby](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support)"

In particular, the third last bullet says:

> Don't use aria-label or aria-labelledby on a span or div unless its given a role.

But again, don't give a random role to your <div> just to force the label to be read.

Essentially, you are looking for the "accessible name" to be read.  The [accessible name calculation](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2) is well defined.

See step 2.F and 2.F.ii regarding "name from content" and looping through child elements in the DOM.  But this again depends on the role.

So, in your situation, without knowing the purpose of your <div>, it's hard to give specific advice.

Comment: My div is like a navigation bar, but each element inside the div is not clickable. Each element indicates a step that user needs to go through. In other words, the div is not intractable by users. My questions is in this case, should I need screen reader to read its content?

Comment: Ah, so it's more of a progress indicator to show you the steps you completed, or the steps you need to complete.  It's not really a "navigation" bar in that you don't use it to navigate to other pages.  For a progress indicator, you can just have all your steps in a list (probably a <ol> since a sequence is implied). A screen reader user can easily navigate to lists and walk through each item.

Comment: I think some of the confusion is regarding how a screen reader is used.  You do **not** need to make an element focusable (`tabindex="0"`) in order for a screen reader user to access the element.  With proper semantic html, such as using an <ol> or <ul>, the screen reader user can use the 'L' key to navigate to a list and the 'I' (eye) key to navigate to each list item.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to make aria-label parse its value by doing:

[aria-label]="{{item.X}}

or am I mixing things up?

Comment: Don't ask a question in an answer.